# Syntax Check on .click function. Can someone spot what's wrong?

Tags: jquery, click

This is a simple click function.  Although it works just fine when using a piece of paragraph text, when I link it to a div that is styled with css, it doesn't work. I have done this before and its worked without a hitch.  I broke something and can't spot it.  Sanity check please?

```
      <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dev.bizzocall.com/css/cpanel.css"  type="text/css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" language="javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                  $("#test1").click(function(){
                    window.location="http://www.google.com";
                  });

                  $("#gobackbutton").click(function(){
                    window.location="http://www.google.com";
                  });

                  $("#copycodebutton").click(function(){
                       window.location="http://www.google.com";
                  });

        </script>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        </head>

        <body>
                <div id="test1">
                   <p>TEST</p>
                </div>
                <div class="clearer"></div>
                <div id ="copycodebutton"></div>
                <div class="clearer"></div>
                <div id ="gobackbutton"></div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(document).ready(function() {` is not closed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
}); // <-- missing
```

Comment: Thanks.  I just saw that.  This was prepared specially for the forum and it got lost along the way.  My problem, was being caused by something happening in another block of jquery that loaded before this one.  I moved my block to the top of the <head> and it works as it should. Thanks for answering!